# how to exterminate sound after exiting app -android-

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

i create app including sound player but when i minimize the app or close it the song still working so how to exterminate sound after minimize or exiting app

here is the code

```
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.emotional);
    end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);

    end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            player.stop();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to stop playing sound when the activity stop.

Try adding

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
       if (player != null)
           player.stop();
       super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Brute-force method is to kill the process (your application):

```
int yourId = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

A bit more subtle solution is to start the music on a separate thread and use this code in your onPause() method:

```
Intent musicIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicClass.class);
getApplicationContext().stopService(musicIntent);
musicThread.stop();
```

Replace `MusicClass.class` with the name of the class in which you play your music, similarily, replace `musicThread` with the name of the thread you started to play the music.